# Extend Roof for Patio Cover

Tags: roof, framing, patio, building-regulations

I have a corner patio area that I want to cover by extending the current roof. The side is 14.5' long and 9.5' wide. The slope is along the 9.5' side.

[image]

I want to extend the roof line marked with blue to match the rest of the roof on that side.

One contractor told me that it wasn't code to do it like I wanted while another said he could do it.

Is it OK to extend the roof? I am in California.

Are there any plans that show something this? I can find many that show a ledger ([San Diego County Patio Cover Plans](http://www.sandiegocounty.gov/pds/docs/pds078.pdf)) but none that attach to the roof in a corner.

Comment: I am  not sure why it would not be to code. Is this going to be a enclosed area living space or patio. There will be different requirements based on the type of construction. Are you going to extend the tile roof or a corrugated clear plastic to allow the light to come through. again there would be a difference in the structure to support a heavy tile compared to a corrugated roof material. With these questions answered we may be able to better help.

Comment: It is going to be an open patio. I did want to match the existing tile roof so you couldn't tell the patio cover part was added -  if possible. I am thinking of a solar tube or skylight for some light.

Comment: With the weight of the tile roof you will probably need to cut several holes in the patio dig them out and pour supports at least 2 possibly 3 depending on the width of the beam to support the load. I see no reason this could not be done but I now live in Oregon.

Comment: Thanks, @EdBeal. I was thinking there would be two supports on the extended side ( I was going to go for 4 x 6 even if 4 x 4 was ok). Do you know of any plans that show the attachment to the roof? The only plans I can find show the ledger attaching to the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Ed Beal. But yes, there are 2 ways to do this & they're equal in strength, for what's planning to be done. However, get a Permit from the Building Dept., so they can approve or correct the design, fasteners & supporting post(s) dimensions & footings. Plus, they can record that the patio was converted to a porch.

1st way is to do ledgers on both fasciae into structural members. Typically you'd pre-build the new structure so the short rafters are end screwed or nailed through the blue-line's ledger & the long lower beam & top ledger are through the side ledger (rafter). Also, use joist hanger type connectors to ensure nothing can pull away from each other.

2nd way is really the proper way & is likely what the one contractor was talking about. You'd remove both fasciae & screw or nail directly into the structure. For the slope side this is much less important. But, the blue-line top would have the new rafters cantilevered or sistered onto the home's existing rafters. This is much more secure & even lets you re-use both fasciae.

Comment: I think sistering (side by side) rafters would better with the weight of a tile roof.

Comment: I ended up going with the guy who went with the second way and just used one support beam and a hangar off the wall for the new header and the rafters where sistered (? next to) to the existing. It would look perfect if he found the right color tile.

Comment: That's fantastic and really the most permanent way to go! I'm sure it's a big improvement in storing things and being able to have a meal or drink protected from the rain or even Sun. I wouldn't doubt the dog(s) use it more than its/their tiny house(s). But yeah, unfortunately, you can only get pre-washed jeans, but not pre-faded roofing.